# Bootstrap CSS - column class error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My page has a static bg image and the text scrolls on a layer "on top" of it. On medium and large devices, I'd like the text to display to the right side of its row to allow for the bg image to be seen - so I added left padding for larger devices. On smaller devices, the text can span all the way across.

I've set the code for both large and small (code for the small devices works if there are no other col classes).  When I add a class for larger devices, it's ignored.

I cannot figure out why the following CSS code won't work.

**CSS**:

```css
.homeBGimg {
    padding: 100px 0 100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/image_1900x1200.jpg);
}
.homeBGimg .even {
     background-image: url(../images/image_1900x1200.jpg); 
} 
.homeBGimg h1 { 
    color: #000; 
}

/* CODE THAT'S DRIVING ME INSANE */

.homeBGimg .col-sm-12 {padding-left: 30px;}
.homeBGimg .col-md-12 {padding-left: 600px;}

/* END OF INSANITY */
```

**HTML**:

```
<section class="homeBGimg">
    <div class="container">    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <h1>Are you prepared for retirement?</h1> 
                <h2>Find out at a complimentary retirement workshop near you.</h2>
                <p>
                    <a href="what-you-should-know.html#videos" 
                    class="btn btn-outline-inverse btn-lg"  
                    data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
                    title="Learn More">
                        Learn More
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The grid system with Bootstrap is set up inside media queries, which if you want to make a responsive site, you also have to use otherwise any styles not inside media queries will be applied to all device widths. In addition, adjusting the grid is not a good idea, figure out another approach

Comment: when an element has this `col-sm-12 col-md-12` then which one will it apply? The last one. Only inside the media queries for these, btw redundant classes as col-sm-12 and col-md-12 is the same thing, will they work, but I would never adjust the grid system for this. Look at the html on GetBootstrap.com the feature or featurette is what is used and there's also examples, you would not need the grid for full width items

Comment: See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E029 for details on why `col-sm-12 col-md-12` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to set CSS styling using two different classes for a div that has both of them. **You can't do that.** Well, you can, but you'll run into the problem you're having.

When working with HTML and CSS, you need to remember that they are read from top to bottom, as you would any document. As such when the browser reads the CSS file, it reads the "rules" in the order they're given, and applies them in that order.

So first you tell it to do this:

```
.homeBGimg .col-sm-12 {padding-left: 30px;}
```

Then you tell it to do this:

```
.homeBGimg .col-md-12 {padding-left: 600px;}
```

For an element that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

Another thing to remember: even though the Bootstrap class isn't techincally applied for that specific width, the class still remains, and **any CSS tied to it will still be applied.**

View this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/knaa44dc/)** to see what's going on. In it, I've applied a border to the item you're targeting with each of the CSS statements you're having issues with. The first one applies a blue border, the second applies an orange one. Notice how only the orange one applies at any viewport width? That's because the rule that applies the orange border comes after the one that applies the blue border, and applies to the same element based on how you've done your DOM targeting, **therefore the furst rule is overridden.**

To do what you want, you'll need to either look into using what are called [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) in CSS, or for a solution using jQuery.

Check out this other **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uyf63to6/)** for an example of how to do this with media queries, and for better targeting.

**HTML**:

```
<section class="homeBGimg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 foo">
                 <h1>Are you prepared for retirement?</h1> 
                 <h2>Find out at a complimentary retirement workshop near you.</h2>

                <p> <a href="what-you-should-know.html#videos" class="btn btn-outline-inverse btn-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Learn More">Learn More</a>

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**:

```
.homeBGimg {
    padding: 100px 0 100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1200);
}
.homeBGimg .even {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1920x1200);
}
.homeBGimg h1 {
    color: #000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .homeBGimg .row div {
        padding-left: 600px;
        border: 1px solid orange;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .homeBGimg .row div {
        padding-left: 30px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
}
```

I hope this gets you started on the right path.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!! Clearly I need to do some studying up! Sucks when you don't know what you don't know! Appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. Development is something you'll always be learning, you never stop, so try not to be hard on yourself for not knowing certain things. :)

Comment: @DesignGal If either of the answers posted helped you, please mark the one that you feel is the best answer to this question as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace this line

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

with this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-6">
```

You don't need that padding at all. Furthermore, it won't work (as you already have noticed. Instead, you need to use the Bootstrap grid. In your specific case, I'm offsetting columns on large views and displaying full width for small screens. Just for reference, I've made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/FxpnxIPwuu) for you to see

Be sure to check [this section of Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) docs which teaches you how to deal with grids and offsetting columns.